# How is the C++ vector class implemented to allow for dynamically re-sizing of arrays?

Tags: c++, vector

How is the C++ vector class implemented to allow for dynamically re-sizing of arrays?

Is it done through a linked-list type of implementation?
Is a new array created from scratch each time an element is added or taken away?

Thanks,
R

Comment: Also note that the linked list implementation although looking attractive, does not fullfill the `std::vector` requirement, which is *the contigious layout in the memory.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical behaviour: Internally, a `std::vector` has a contiguous array of length `capacity`.  At any given point, only `size` elements are actually being used.  If at any point `size` would exceed `capacity` (let's say you called `push_back()` a lot), a new, bigger, internal array is allocated (`capacity` might double, say).  Then all the elements from the old array are copied into the new one, and the old elements and array are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The details are implementation dependent but the memory block allocated by vector is guaranteed to be continuous.

GCC is using 2.0 coefficient when reallocating memory, MSVC is using 1.5 coefficient.

Comment: there was a discussion a while ago on c++.lang.moderated regarding the optimal coefficient, with the notable participation of Alexandrescu, and I think they deduced that it was `alpha` (positive root of `x^2 = x + 1`)

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations use a simple array and double the capacity whenever the array becomes full. This does involve copying the existing elements to a new block of memory but it is compensated by the fact that you won't have to do this again for quite some time. (Using such a technique, element additions run in amortized constant time.)